# What is consciousness

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

Is it a question that science may answer? This article became the root of my thinking. 
https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/mar/01/consciousness-eight-questions-science

Comment: It is a question science can answer.. and in fact is very close to answering.

Comment: Please summarize the Guardian article to help focus answers.

Comment: I'll add a comment to replace my answer. Of course empirical science cannot tell us what consciousness is. It cannot even find it. One neuroscientist (Varella) comments that searching for consciousness in the brain is like 'searching for gravity by digging into the Earth'.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking should this question get the "sensitive" warning?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - I'd say definitely.it should. Correction to previous comment - It was Pepperel not Varella who made that comment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Generic questions such as yours are not really suitable for our format. There is no answer, rather a centuries long philosophical controversy, which is best addressed by reading encyclopedias, see e.g. [Consciousness on SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/). We take more pointed questions that can be more or less objectively answered within reasonable space.

Comment: It may be the only word with more definitions than 'run'.  Consequently, it is better to use almost any other word for whatever you actually want defined.

Answer (score 5):

There are famous arguments in the literature to the effect that the answer is an emphatic "no".

If by consciousness you mean something like a private, qualitative and intentional "first-person" experience, something that is not really communicable, then it would seem that no public and objective "third-person" description will ever account for it, simply because of missing conceptual or linguistic resources. Another way to say this is that science describes relational, nomological, extrinsic aspects of the world, but not its intrinsic nature, because the former are the only objectivable aspects.

The famous arguments to that effect are:

- Nagel's contention that no physiological description of a bat's sensory organs will ever tell you "what it's like to be a bat",  what it feels like to perceive by echolocation,
- Jackson's thought experiment where Mary, a neuroscientist raised in a colourless environment, sees red for the first time and "learns" something even though she knew exactly what would happen in her brain, and
- Chalmers's claim that physical states exactly like our bodies', including all neuronal states, and thus indistinguishable from the outside but lacking the qualitative experience inside, such "zombie" states are perfectly conceivable, which means that no physical description can ever account for qualitative experience.

These arguments have been widely discussed and they do not convince everyone (Dennett calls them "intuition pumps") but it seems reasonable to assume that the problem of consciousness has a strong metaphysical component that is not up for direct empirical enquiry. Presumably, the role of neuroscience is limited to telling us about the "neural correlates" of consciousness (what kinds of neuronal structures or processes do instantiate conscious states) but an explanatory gap remains, and it can only be filled by metaphysical assumptions. This doesn't mean that neuroscience tells us nothing informative about consciousness, but that its scope is fundamentally limited.

Having said that, making a positive point for an intrinsic limitation of scientific explanations in this domain runs into deep epistemological, semantic and methodological issues that are at the core of philosophy. This is why this debate is not yet settled.

Comment: Are the examples you cite actually a rationale against science investigating first person experience?  I have always taken them as an argument against a purely 3rd person empiricism.  They show that functionalism or behaviorism is not able to understand consciousness, as they leave out the key characteristics of consciousness.  But science/empiricism can be and is applied to the first person -- we have an entire science field, psychology, which is a first person field.

Comment: This approach presumes the current accepted definition for "science", which is to say, "ontological materialism".

Comment: @elliot svensson , Science does not presume an ontology.  It instead applies a methodology: exploration, speculation, guided exploration, hypothesis, test, revision, retest, etc.  See Karl Popper.  Science can be materialist, dualist, idealist, or any ontology.  That is how the peculiarities of Quantum behavior can basically refute materialism.

Comment: @Dcleve - Is not all empiricism first-person?

Comment: @PeterJ -- yes, all empiricism starts with first person data.

Comment: @Dcleve no these arguments are directed against the investigation of first person qualitative aspects by science. Scientific psychology studies behaviours and first person reports, but nothing in psychology tells us "what it's like" to experience, say, fear: at most it informs us about functional relations between various emotions and other experiences, but not their intrinsic qualities.

Comment: @PeterJ actually not all versions of empiricism start with first person data. Most contemporary versions (such as van Fraassen's) do not, because of problems with foundationalism in epistemology and sense data theories (Sellar's "myth of the given" for example): they start with a notion of observable that corresponds to an objective property of phenomena, something like public accessibility to members of our epistemic community. This is already a 3rd person concept...

Comment: @elliotsvensson This approach presumes some sort of scientific realism I guess, but anti-realist positions are generally *less* optimistic about what science can study so... I think more generally the problem has to do with the fact that science must be publicly accessible, objective knowledge, whereas qualitative aspects are (intuitively at least) private and inexpressible. Recognising an experience of yellow and knowing that people say "this is yellow"in such circumstances does nothing to describe what it's like to see yellow. That's the main intuition that drives these arguments I think.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant, you mean that science can't, and perhaps shouldn't, answer all our questions?

Comment: @elliotsvensson I mean there are these arguments that it can't. They ultimately rely on intuitions so there's still room for debate but I find them quite compelling.

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant, both Nagel and Searle consider the first person to be subject to scientific inquiry:  http://www.markwk.com/2008/04/philosophy-and-the-scientific-world-view-by-john-searle.html https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/is-scientific-materialism-almost-certainly-false/ It is simply false to say that their throught problems challenged the limts of science -- they were explicitly challenging REDUCTIONSM, not science.

Comment: @Dcleve right, these arguments are primarily directed against physicalism, which only means that consciousness cannot be studied by *physics*. I didn't mention Searle... But Nagel says (as reported in the article you linked) that science *as practiced today* is inadequate and he calls for radical refoundations. I'm not sure what he has in mind exactly and whether it would still be "science"... Chalmers claims that the problem of consciousness is not a scientific ("easy") problem but a metaphysical ("hard") one. So I think it's fair to say that those arguments point towards limits of science.

Comment: Also, Jackson's argument mentions neuroscience, not physics.

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant, I follow Popper on what science is (the applicaiton of methodologcal naturalism and falsifiability tests).  These can be done on first person.  Popper also holds by a weak border between science, philosophy, and informal empiricism.  One does informal first person empiricism every day, starting when one wakes up, examines one's sensations, and infers where one is, that one's bladder is full, etc.

Comment: @Dcleve that's one thing to take first person experiences as inputs for knowledge. I don't know anyone who rejects that. That's another to pretend that you can *explain* them from science. You wouldn't pretend that physicists, when they study, say, the laws of optics in a laboratory, are actually studying their own consciousness, simply because they rely on their observations, would you? So why would it be any different for neuropsychologists?

Comment: @Dcleve if this was an answer to my comment on empiricism, I think one of the main achievements of 20th philosophy of science is to have shown that sense-data based epistemologies are doomed to fail. It would be too long to explain here I guess you'll find references elsewhere but as a quick note: 1/first person reports are not always reliable and science strives to achieve interpersonal, cross-contextual stability of measurements and 2/ the "what it's like" to have your bladder full is not what counts in your inferences, as opposed to the conceptually articulated content "my bladder is full"

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant , our self model is developed during toddlerhood from first person empiricism -- so yes, I consider consciousness to be explicitly studiable by the sceintific method.  In response to your claim that it is "conceptually articulated content" that matters, this is falsified by the experiences of those people who suffered loss of language:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4874898/  more:  https://owlcation.com/humanities/thinking-thoughts-without-language

Comment: Relative to science -- first person experience is not infallible.  Infallibility is not required for foundational data.  Empiricism is fault tolerant, and robust.  Do you have links to this 20th century refutation of indirect realism?

Comment: @Dcleve rejecting foundationalism does not mean that perception plays no role (no one goes that far), only that it's not exclusive. There are plenty of resources since logical empiricism and its rejection in the second half of 20th century are foundational in contemporary philosophy of science. If you want historical sources Kuhn (scientific revolutions) and Quine (two dogmas) are prominent. Otherwise you have this article, with a paragraph on sense data https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perception-episprob/#SensData and this one https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-foundational/

Comment: @Dcleve for the conceptual articulation problem this paragraph is relevant https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-foundational/#SellDile

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant , These links primarily describe a desire to believe in the certianty of our world as the objection to foundationalism -- but as nobody can refute the Great Deciever hypothesis -- this desire is both the fallacy of wishful thinking, AND is based on a refuted premise.  I am missing the refutation of indrect realism.  Two dogmas does not refute indirect realism, and in that paper, Quine himself greatly overstates what the consequences of his observations are. Here is my evaluation. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BOnLu_ffkHiSMt7XcNib6synqyS6SIZzIhYKxYX_2xk/edit

Comment: Sellars directly attacks foundationalism, but I find his argument to be flawed in two ways:  he claims that knoweldge must be proposiitonal.  But we have examples of non-linguistic thinking, so we know that isn't true.  He also asserts that one cannot get from data to knowledge -- without presenting an explicit proof of this claim.  But we get from data to knowledge all the time-- so once more his assertions are empirically falsified.  I think he assumes that the process is only valid if it is logically necressry -- but empiricism can NEVER meet that standard - it meets pragamatic truth metric

Comment: @Dcleve I think the discussion is going a bit too far. The encyclopedia entries give the current state of the art on these issues. If you think you have something to bring you can try to publish it but as far as I know, sense-data style empiricism is long dead and a dose of coherentism is seen as essential to epistemology. About your comments on Sellars: of course we always go from data to belief, but it's a problem of *justification*, and scientific knowledge, if it is to be transmitted, is certainly propositional. But I think we've lost the connection to my initial answer so I'll stop here

Comment: @Dcleve just to return to the start of the discussion: even if sense-data empiricism was the true epistemology of science, the fact that knowledge is *based on* first person experience does not mean that it is *about* first person experience. So how is it relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is an emphatic "yes".  This was a change in perspective, as for ~50 years in the middle of the 20th century science (and philosophy) tended to avoid questions about consciousness.

However, the last two decades of the 20th century saw an increasing interest both among philosophers and scientists in understanding ourselves, and in particular our consciousness.  And this project has continued to grow in the 21st century.  A key advocate for this effort was Francis Crick, who set out to inspire and recruit a generation of neurologists to try to crack this last mystery.  He outlined his own views in The Astonishing Hypothesis:  http://www.consciousentities.com/crick.htm

Crick, and many of his inspirees, ASSUME neuro reductionism.  And therefore treat "scientific study" as == "neurological characterization".  The author of your Guardian piece is a materialist reductionist as well.

However, the achievemetns of the neuro-reductionist project have not been nearly as successful as Crick and his initial inspirees hoped.  One of the reasons is a logic problem, with the Guardian article mentions only obiquely.

- IF nero reductionism is true
- THEN all causation attributed to    consciousness is fully
  explainable in purely neurological terms
- THEREFORE the apparent causation for "conscious" events is basically 
  illusory
- AND THEN consciousness is an illusion or an epiphenomenon

But the author (and most other people who intimately experience it) is not willing to accept consciousness is an epiphenomenon.  However, as he is not willing to give up on reductionism, he explicitly declares a limited goal of exploring mechanisms of consciousness, and has given up on understanding why it exists at all.

A significant number of consciousness researchers have abandoned neuro reductionism. Christof Koch, Crick's own primary collaborator is among them.  He is now an advocate of Integrated Information Theory, which is an architectural and  organizational approach to consciousness, as opposed to a neuro-reductionist one. IIT, Global Workspace Theory, and Higher Order Processing, among others, are IT inspired approaches to investigating consciousness, that equate consciousness to running a particualr algorithm, rather than having a particular set of neurons.  This is Algortithmic Identity Theory, rather than Neural Identity Theory.    Koch is also willing to consider either pan-psychism, or property emergence, rather than material reductionism, as alternative ontologies.

Another major area of science thinking in investigating consciousness is to revive idealism.  Here is a recent collection of thinking about experimental data relative to consciousness, and how it supports an idealist ontology:  https://www.bernardokastrup.com/2015/03/review-of-beyond-physicalism.html

So, while "YES -- science can study consciousness", your linked author's approach is already looking to be at best useful but not relevatory, and there are at least two other major scientific paradigms being deployed to engage in this investigation.

Comment: This approach is contingent on redefining "science"!

Comment: @elliotsvensson - Quite so, I wish we would.

Comment: @elliot svensson, I just detailed three different scientific paradigms that are being used today to investigte consciousness.  No "redefinition" is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm not trying to cause trouble here but cannot discover why my first answer was deleted. So, here it is again with a couple of tweaks. If it is to be deleted I'd appreciate some advice as to what is wrong with it.]

'What is consciousness?' is not a question empirical science can answer. This is a matter of logic and should be obvious from a literature review. Consciousness is not an empirical phenomenon. There is no accounting for the idea that consciousness may be studied empirically since it is obviously not the case. It seems to arise from wishful thinking and a suspension of logical reasoning.

If by 'science' we mean empirical science then the phrase 'scientific consciousness studies' is an oxymoron. I am not the first person to point this out. This problem reveals itself in the literature which may be observed to be a morass of sophistry going nowhere.

The layman may learn a lot about the current scientific mind-set from a study of scientific consciousness studies as well as much about brains, cognition and behaviour, but nothing about consciousness. Its existence and definition remain a matter of debate because, inevitably, it is not studied by the empirical sciences, which must be content with observing brains, cognition and behaviour.

This is not a matter of opinion. Consciousness, experience and awareness are not empirical phenomena. This is a fact. The study of consciousness is not merely the study of behaviour, brains or neural correlates just as the study of fire is not merely the study of smoke. The existence and nature of consciousness cannot be learned from empirical research for this cannot even establish its existence. I'm not sure why anyone would think otherwise.

You might like to check out two old articles for the Journal of Consciousness Studies by David Chalmers, 'Facing Up to the Problem of Consciousness' and 'Moving on from...'. They are not a solution to anything but they do at least describe the mountain to be climbed by those who want to reduce the non-empirical to the empirical.

A further problem is that even if consciousness were an empirical phenomenon science would be unable to tell you what it is. Physics does not address the question of what things are for this is the territory of metaphysics. Science cannot tell you what matter is so it would be optimistic to hope it can do better with consciousness. It's a question of 'horses for courses'. Each approach has value within its domain but is limited to that domain.

*One can no more hope to find consciousness by digging into the brain than one can find gravity by digging into the earth’s centre’.*

Robert Peperell ‘Between phenomenology and neuroscience’ A report of the ‘Towards a Science of Consciousness’ Conference, Prague, July 2003) From JCS Vol 10 No 11 2003 p 87

Comment: PeterJ could you provide the logical reasoning as to why consciousness is not empirical, rather than asserting it?  I assume you do not accept first person empiricism.  But first person empiricism is critical in psychology -- all its data relies upon the first person.  Also, how do you figure out where you are when you wake up, other than 1st person empiricism?  Here is the dalai lama advocating for it: https://www.lionsroar.com/first-person-science-march-2012/

Comment: @Dcleve - Are you saying, contrary to Descartes, that consciousness is 'res extensa'? I'm not sure what reasoning I could give for consciousness being non-empirical when it so obviously is. I would ask how we would detect it with our physical senses. Surely nobody argues this is possible,

Comment: @PeterJ of course there are arguments for physically sensing consciousness - positivistic take on the "hard problem" that claims neuroscience is how we physically examine "consciousness".

Comment: @peterJ why would you limit detection to physical senses?  The physical is an indirect inference, and the vast bulk of "senses" are not experinced directly, but are massivley post-processed. When you read "The Man Who Mistook His Wife for A Hat", and see how bits of consciousness are lost in various patients, how can you say anything other than "we can't investigate consciousness scientifically" is explicitly falsified?

Comment: @Dcleve - Empiricism is the idea that all knowledge is derived from the physical senses. Our knowledge of consciousness is not empirical. I am not limiting anything but noting that empiricism is a limited method of detection and cannot detect consciousness.  .

Comment: @PeterJ Empiricism is just the process of using observations and testing to establish what there is.   As all observations are first person, there is nothing unique about consciousness and our observations of it that exclude it from empirical study.  As the physical is an inference from empiricism, it is logiclaly contradictory to limit empiricism to the physical, one would never end up inferring the physical in the first place of one did that!  Science, which is just a formalization of empiricism, is not limited to physical senses, unless you say psychology is not a science.

Comment: @Dcleve - I'm using the dictionary definition of 'empiricism' but you seem to be speaking of something else. Knowledge of consciousness does not come to us via the physical senses and is therefore not empirical.

Comment: @PeterJ -- Wikipedia, SEP, and Britannica all describe empiricism as based on sense experience, or sometimes just experience.  Physical is not central.  https://www.britannica.com/topic/empiricism  Starting with definitions is not the way I do philosophy anyway, even though this definition check backs me up -- definiitons describe usage and practice, and philosophy is still an open field, so usage and practice are variable and changing.

Comment: @Dcleve - I wish 'empiricism' included direct non-sensory experience but I can't argue with common usage.

Comment: @Dcleve - I find that reference you give to be rather unhelpful. It stresses the importance of experience but does not comment on the issue of whether all 'knowledge by experience' is acquired from the senses. I'll check out a couple more since maybe you have a point. I hope you do because to me empiricism should mean all experience, not just that derived from the senses. But the dictionaries make the rules. Wiki says "In philosophy, empiricism is a theory that states that knowledge comes only or primarily from sensory experience...".

Comment: @Dcleve One argument to support the claim that consciousness is not an observable phenomena is that we cannot perceive through senses other people's consciousness (this depends on how we define consciousness of course but here I'm interested in the qualitative experience of others). Arguably we do not, strictly speaking, perceive our own consciousness either: rather our consciousness concerns the very fact that we perceive something *else*.

Comment: @Dcleve having said that, not all scientific posits are directly observable so consciousness could be posited to *explain* other phenomena (such as 1st person reports? Or complex behaviour?). The problem here is that purely qualitative aspects seem explanatory idle. They seem to play no causal roles. At least that's what some philosophers argue.

Comment: @PeterJ dictionaries do not "make the rules", they report on usage:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-words-into-dictionary  The concept of first person empiricism being how we develop our self-model, world model, and model of other minds, is widely accepted in development psychology: https://www.spring.org.uk/2008/07/jean-piagets-four-stage-theory-how.php

Comment: @Quentin Ruyant , I am a foundationalist, in that we cannot know anything unless we have inputs, and working rules, and our experiences, and our instinctual basic reasoning, are those inputs and rules.  Neither of these are unquestioned, after all, we know that our basic reasonign is often wrong, hence we developed formal reasoning, and we have false memories and false impressions, so have learned to apply consistency testing and skepticism even to our own direct experiences.

Comment: @Dcleve - It is simply a fact that if I suggest that that Yoga is an empirical science I will be attacked by many scientists and philosophers for misusing this word. I'm not sure what empiricism can be except first-person and I feel it is much safer in philosophical discussions to restrict its use to evidence from our senses, which some argue is the only evidence there ever can be.   .  .

Comment: @PeterJ , if you can show that Yoga meets Popper's criteria, then just tell these critics they are wrong about what science is, and cite Popper.

Comment: @Dcleve - I prefer to stick to common usage on the word 'empirical' (albeit I see your point) but I'm happy to stick to my guns when calling Yoga a science since it is one even by a common usage of the word. That's a discussion for another time.

Answer (score 1):

Consciousness is the only aspect of reality that is not verifiably vanishable.  Even blackouts are only verifiably black-ins, with a last moment of blackness being recalled before coming-to.

As I wrote in an essay for the Journal of Consciousness Studies, there is a legitimate science of correlation between brain states and consciousness, but no science of consciousness itself.

https://www.scienceandnonduality.com/article/science-and-consciousness-just-wed-should-this-union-be-annulled

Comment: Nice article. I share your view. The method can be scientific but the ontology cannot be materialism. Ontology is for metaphysicians. Quite why materialism is seen as uniquely scientific or even necessary to science is a mystery. Why would a physicist feel it necessary to adopt a dogmatic ontology, and how can this be good science? It looks like  misunderstanding of science. .

Answer (score 0):

In short, **Consciousness is our collective experience of sensing time & space.** This is my personal definition. It may appear elusive until we understand it properly. Now, I will elaborate on the definition. The mechanism of an 'experience' is processing of the information in the brain. By 'sensing time & space', I meant sensing passage of time with respect to our body or that we are indeed moving through time in a single direction (by movement here I meant we know our body can occupy *only an instant* along time axis & that is changing in a single direction) **&** sensing that we as a *'modified mass'* has a spatial extent as well as we (or our body parts) can move through space (or basically manipulate space in some way atleast weakly). I refer *'modified mass'* here to any mass having constituents inside it such that they work together so as to give the emergent phenomenon of life i.e. any mass with life. Because I have included 'movement' into the definition, one might argue -so what about plants? They are life forms too. In the course of life of a plant its 'body parts' like the roots or the stem do change positions by growing though the plant as a whole is stationary fixed to the ground. Thus plants are conscious to some extent. I attribute consciousness only to living beings or any mass with life; not non-living things though.

So why consciousness? I understand it as follows. All living things have mass. Any mass (whether living or non-living) occupy space as well as move through time. I have searched a lot about the definition of mass in physics. What I could understand is that it is a property of matter by which it moves through time & occupies space. By *'matter'* I meant 'any 'stuff' in the universe that can interact atleast weakly with similar 'stuff' '.Now, any mass has a 'frame of reference'. By latter I meant a personal way of describing a phenomenon occurring with regards to time & space. One such phenomenon is called as motion. So what is motion? According to me, motion can never occur in a world with dimensions that are purely spatial. It can occur only if there is atleast 1 spatial & atleast 1 temporal dimension. Also motion is something that occurs for a mass or an energy packet (eg: photon) (as perceived by another mass). A mass can never say whether it itself is really moving or not. Only other masses can say whether the mass is moving or not relative to them. So motion is relative. Its also because of non existence of an absolute reference frame in our real universe. So coming back to the concept of frame of reference, in order to have it, the 'thing' has to move through time as well as occupy space. Because it mandates the 'thing' to have mass, its possible only for a mass. A photon (an energy packet of light) because it is massless has no frame of reference. Thus if we were to hypothetically explain to a photon what is space & time, it could never understand it! Thus a photon can never understand the concept of motion. A photon experiences no time or space. The latter sentence is in fact wrong in some sense & correct in some sense. And that's this- Because photon has no frame of reference we cant really talk about photon 'experiencing' 'anything'. But I said so *just for the sake of understanding it easily*. So would a photon be conscious? No. So coming back to the fact that any mass has a frame of reference- If the mass is a modified mass ( meaning it has intrinsic mechanisms that work together to generate life) , it will have a mechanism to sense time & space too for it to appropriately function. And this is consciousness. So consciousness is a part of the definition of life. All living beings are conscious. Non-living mass too move through time & occupy space (because they are too 'mass'). But they don't have that intrinsic mechanism to sense whether they are moving through time or whether they are occupying indeed a space. Hence they don't have consciousness. So you can now use the definition of consciousness to define a living being or life. A living being is a mass with consciousness. And life is the worldline of a living being in the 4 dimensional spacetime. By worldline I meant the entire path of a living being from its birth till its death in the higher dimensional world of 4 dimensions( ie spacetime).

Note: I have mentioned frequently here *'moving along time'* though 'motion of a mass' is how position changes with respect to time for the mass. I used 'moving along time' just for the sake of understanding things easily. We don't usually use the inverse of speed to explain things. I understand that all of our life maybe predetermined i.e. our worldline maybe already present in the 4 dimensional world as a solid block. But then what is then exactly causing us to feel as if we are moving through time? Or that as if we are having a plane of 'now'? I think its our mass. The notion of motion of mass in space with respect to time is more familiar than the reverse. Hence I used *'moving through time'* here to understand things more easily.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!